# Inno Setup 6.0.5 always create new uninstaller file which doest not have signature

Tags: installation, inno-setup, code-signing

I upgrade the Inno Setup from 5 to 6 recently.

Build script and iss files are not changed, however, the build always failed in Inno Setup 6 environment.

The failed point is in the signed uninstaller.

```
[Setup]
SignedUninstaller = yes
SignedUninstallerDir=Release\
```

For create an uninstaller with digital sign, I set `SignedUninstaller=yes` in my `setup.iss`, I didn't set SignTool since my signature is given by other service, which I need using other script to sign instead.

In inno setup 5 environment, it created a new uninstaller `uninst-5.5.9 (u)-xxxxxx.e32` file at first time, I took this to do signature by other service then put it back to the `Release\` folder.

Recompile my build script, it shows *"Using existing signed uninstaller file: uninst-5.5.9 (u)-xxxxxx.e32"* which I have add signed before to create uninstaller. Everything is work well in Inno Setup 5.

However, I only upgrade inno setup to 6.0.5, the thing is totally different, the file name of uninstaller is changed in each compile, always shows *"Creating new signed uninstaller file: uninst-6.0.5 (u)-xxxxxxxx.e32"*, which cause that the approach I do in Inno Setup 5 cannot be work here.

I notice that the compile log is quite different here...

Inno Setup 5

```
Preparing Setup program executable
   Updating icons (SETUP.E32)
   Using existing signed uninstaller file:
```

Inno Setup 6

```
Preparing Setup program executable
   Updating icons (SETUP.E32)
   Updating version info (SETUP.E32)
   Creating new signed uninstaller file:
```

The code is totally same, only upgrade the Inno Setup compiler.

Does anyone know the difference between 5 and 6?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [6.0.4](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is6.0-whatsnew.htm#6.0.4), Inno Setup includes the version info of your application (product name, product version, company, copyright, etc) into the uninstaller. It is a part of this change:

> Windows AppLocker publisher conditions are now supported by Setup up to and including the file name level.

---

So the uninstaller is now different for each application. That indeed kind of cancels the intended caching effect of [`SignedUninstallerDir`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signeduninstallerdir).